# Correct Schema.org type for B2B product (not e-commerce)

Tags: schema.org, products

What is the correct Schema.org type for a product page that is not sold online? For example, a B2B product that requires contact with a salesperson to purchase (i.e. enterprise software/hardware).

I've seen [`Product`](https://schema.org/Product) but this seems to be applicable for e-commerce, i.e. something that a customer can buy on the website.

Answer (score 1):

[**`Product`**](https://schema.org/Product) is the correct type. It’s not just for e-commerce. Its description says:

> Any offered product or service.

It doesn‘t matter where/how it’s offered; it doesn’t even have to be offered by you, it just needs to be "offerable" in theory.

For the actual offer, you need to use the [**`Offer`**](https://schema.org/Offer) type. You can connect `Product` and `Offer` with the [`offers`](https://schema.org/offers) property (or [`itemOffered`](https://schema.org/itemOffered) in the other direction).

In your case, you could provide an `Offer` without `price`/`priceSpecification`. You won’t get Google’s Product rich result, because [it requires a price](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product#offer_properties), so don’t wonder about errors in the [SDTT](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=en) related to this.